# Export of plot depends on kernel

Tags: export, kernel

I am trying to export a log-plot to a pdf-file but the logarithmic axis ticks are broken when exporting from my default kernel `local`. The exported pdf is as expected when setting the notebook kernel to a secondary kernel `secondary`.

A minimal example is: `Evaluation->Notebook's Kernel->local`

```
data = {#, # RandomReal[{.9, 1.1}, 30] // Exp}\[Transpose] &@(
Range@30/3);  
plot = ListLogPlot[data];  
Export["~/Desktop/logPlotLoc.pdf", Show[plot, ImageSize -> 250]];
```

Then change kernel:
`Evaluation->Notebook's Kernel->secondary`

```
data = {#, # RandomReal[{.9, 1.1}, 30] // Exp}\[Transpose] &@(
Range@30/3);  
plot = ListLogPlot[data];  
Export["~/Desktop/logPlotSec.pdf", Show[plot, ImageSize -> 250]];
```

The unexpected result is:[image: Exported from <code>local</code>]

[image: Exported from <code>secondary</code>]

Both kernels were newly started. How is this possible and can I prevent it somehow?

I am using Mathematica 11.2.0.0 on a Mac.

Comment: Please do not use the bugs tag unless the bug is confirmed by this community.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue using Mathematica 11.3.0 on Windows 10 (64-Bit).

Comment: @gwr 1) Okay. 2) It came from the ancient past of the code and has been sent back there, sorry. 3) Thank you for trying! The mystery remains...

Comment: @Stalpotaten and these kernels are truly identical? I'm skeptical of that. Can you do the same test, but run `$Version` instead of your plots, perhaps? I cannot reproduce this from 11.3 on macOS 10.14.

Comment: Is the `plot` itself correct, and only the ticks are incorrect on export?

Comment: @user6014 1) The version is `"11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"` on both kernels.   2) The plots are all good, it is only the logarithmic ticks that are lost in the `local` kernel at exportation. The plot within Mathematica is fine and saving the graph manually gives correct ticks (albeit the wrong image size by some reason).   3) This problem have persisted for weeks but this morning when I tried to reproduce it, both kernels gave the desired output. If I hadn't the faulty files saved I would think I'm mad. I'll see if I can reproduce it again before closing the issue.